# Create system snapshot to use applications that are not installed

Tags: windows-7, snapshot

Sorry if the title doesn't really give an overview of what this is.
I need an application that can do a system snapshot.
Here's the story. I have deepfreeze installed right now. And its activated. 
If I install an application then restart. It won't commit to the hard disk. 
What I want to do now, is to be able to create a system snapshot while the application is installed.
And to be able to call that snapshot and use that certain application. 
This is because I only have limited space on my disk. And I only want to install the apps that I use everyday. 
Do you have an idea on how I can achieve something like that?

Comment: wouldn't the snapshot use as much space as the real installation?

Comment: I'm going to put the snapshot in an external hd. which has greater space. I just don't want to clutter the registry with program files.